# How to remove appended .0 to date values? ex. [2014-06-13 11:39:18.0]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, spring-mvc

**Enviroment:**

- hibernate
- MySql 5.6 (date is type DATETIME)
- Spring 3.2
- Java (date is type java.util.Date)
- jdbc (mysql-connector-java 5.1.27)

When I recover the date value from the database and I print it out in html page I get 
this value [2014-06-13 11:39:18.0] with a finish dot zero.

I could format before print it ino html, but I don't understand why is that **.0** appended to the date.

When I edit a register through the web and updated, the init binder with format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is getting an error

```
...on field 'date': rejected value [2014-06-13 11:39:18.0]; 
codes [typeMismatch.action.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
 arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [action.date,date]; arguments [];
 default message [date]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date for value '2014-06-13 11:39:18.0'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]]
```

I found this [MySql Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8428) that seems to be a problem alike.

Another similar case with an old jdbc mysql connector, [more info](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-printview-t-5978-start-0.html).

Comment: Which bean do you want? 
  <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/myData" id="dataSource"
   expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"></jee:jndi-lookup>

Comment: That bug is old, but it seems that has come again. And It seems to be the jdbc mysql connector, because I found another similar case and it was resolved by using an older version of jdbc mysql connector.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert the `String` to `Date` before persisting the value.

at your entity annotate the Date field :

```
@Entity
public class MyClass{
//Id and other fields
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DATE_FIELD")
private Date mydate;
}
```

`DATE_FIELD` will contain values this format : `2014-07-16`

Or you can use :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATE_FIELD")
private Date mydate;
```

`DATE_FIELD` will contain values this format: `2014-07-16 11:30:39`

Comment: I'm getting the same error, when I print the date in html, I still get the .0